# Uninitialized constant error in Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, require

I am modeling a web application where you can get to another application page by clicking some link. I decided to do something like this:

file `C:/Sandbox/common_page.rb`:

```
require_relative "./pageA"
require_relative "./pageB"
require_relative "./pageC"
require_relative "./pageD"
class CommonPage
  def pageA
    # click_pageA_link
    pageA.new
  end
  def pageB
    # click_pageB_link
    pageB.new
  end
  def pageC
    # click_pageC_link
    pageC.new
  end
  def pageD
    # click_pageD_link
    pageD.new
  end
  # and so on for other pages..
end
```

file `C:/Sandbox/pageA.rb`:

```
require_relative "./common_page"
class PageA < CommonPage
  def pageA
    self
  end
end
```

file `C:/Sandbox/pageB.rb`:

```
require_relative "./common_page"
class PageB < CommonPage
  def pageB
    self
  end
end
```

Similar code would be presented for classes representing other pages. If I run file `C:/Sandbox/test.rb` with this code:

```
require_relative "./pageA"
pA = PageA.new
```

I get this error:

```
C:/Sandbox/pageB.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CommonPage (NameError)
    from C:/Sandbox/common_page.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from C:/Sandbox/common_page.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Sandbox/pageA.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from C:/Sandbox/pageA.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Sandbox/test.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from C:/Sandbox/test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Similar error pops up also when I try to create instances of other classes. Could somebody explain what is happening here and how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, circular dependency cannot be met. If egg requires hen, and hen hatches from an egg, then if you don't have any yet, you don't have any. Why must `common_page.rb` require `pageA`? Remove the requires from `common_page.rb`, make a separate `my_project.rb`, create a `my_project` directory, move all other files in it, and require them from `my_project.rb` as follows:

```
require_relative 'my_project/common_page'
require_relative 'my_project/pageA'
require_relative 'my_project/pageB'
require_relative 'my_project/pageC'
require_relative 'my_project/pageD'
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the require lines in common_page to the bottom of that file.

The problem is that pageA requires common_page, which requires pageA (already in progress), proceeding on common_page requires pageB, which in turn requires common_page (already in progress) and then proceeds to reference CommonPage which hasn't yet been defined.

Comment: Which is called a ”circular dependency”.

Comment: @Sam thanks for the explanation! 
Is the circular reference thing I should avoid in my design? Is there another/better way to achieve what I wanted?